# jQuery on change table values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning jQuery and want to change values inside a table `td`. I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#s1').on('change', function() {
    $("#lev1,#lev2,#lev3,#lev4,#lev5").text(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="s1">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="50">30</option>
  <option value="90">40</option>
</select>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 5</td>
      <td id="lev5">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 4</td>
      <td id="lev4">1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 3</td>
      <td id="lev3">500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 2</td>
      <td id="lev2">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 1</td>
      <td id="lev1">100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to show level values as:

- for option 10: `var  = [19,39,49,79,199]`
- for option 20: `var  = [39,49,79,199,239]`
- for option 50: `var  = [49,79,199,239,299]`
- for option 90: `var  = [79,199,239,299,399]`

How can I do this? I am new to this and have learned just the basics of jQuery. A bit of an example of what I have done: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FCLNW59MAXD1

Answer (score 2):

Save your data in a json object and use [jQuery.text( function )](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function).

You may also use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) in order to reduce the code.

The snippet:

```js
var r = {
  '10': [19, 39, 49, 79, 199],
  '20': [39, 49, 79, 199, 239],
  '50': [49, 79, 199, 239, 299],
  '90': [79, 199, 239, 299, 399]
};
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#s1').on('change', function (e) {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $('[id^="lev"]').text(function (idx, text) {
      return r[v][idx];
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<table class="table" style="width:50%;background:#E5B794;color:#111;text-align:center;border-radius:12px;padding:10px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Level 5</td>
        <td id="lev5">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Level 4</td>
        <td id="lev4">1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Level 3</td>
        <td id="lev3">500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Level 2</td>
        <td id="lev2">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Level 1</td>
        <td id="lev1">100</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<select id="s1" style="width:48%;border-radius:12px;background:#E5B794;color:#111;">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">30</option>
    <option value="90">40</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like charm and one step forward for my jquery learning

Comment: Need a bit more help, I need to know which value he selected(played) as on click I need to pass that value to databse

Comment: @john The selected value  is the variable v, or $(this).val()

Comment: @john In this case the value of the array is the value:  r[v]. is IT?  Let me know

Comment: @john In order to print it in the console you can use JSON.stringify(r[v]) To append this value to a div you can write:  $('div').append(JSON.stringify(r[v]));

Comment: Sorry but I shut down computer. If the array value is r[v]. The first value is r[v][0]....

Comment: can u plz take a look on my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184386/decimals-for-negative-php-values

Answer (score 1):

You can put all those values and arrays in one object and then you can just use `forEach` loop, so each element in array with match with index of row.

```js
var values = {
  10: [19, 39, 49, 79, 199],
  20: [39, 49, 79, 199, 239],
  50: [49, 79, 199, 239, 299],
  90: [79, 199, 239, 299, 399]
}
$('select').change(function() {
  values[$(this).val()].forEach(function(e, i) {
    $('table tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('td:nth-child(2)').text(e)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="50">30</option>
  <option value="90">40</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 5</td>
      <td id="lev5">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 4</td>
      <td id="lev4">1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 3</td>
      <td id="lev3">500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 2</td>
      <td id="lev2">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 1</td>
      <td id="lev1">100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you plz take a look on my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184386/decimals-for-negative-php-values