# Decimals For negative PHP values

Tags: php, jquery

I am writing a bit of php code to output a random value

```
$max_mal = (3 - $oray);
$oray       =   1;
$max        =   100;
$total = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max_mal; $i++){
      $goli = mt_rand(3, 8);
      $total += $goli;
        $golis[] = $goli;
    }
```

and for each loop goes here

```
    foreach($golis as &$goli) {
        $goli = floor(($goli / $total) * $max);
          if ($goli == 0) {
            $goli = 1;
          }
     }
    $result =   array_pad($golis, 3, -1);
    shuffle($result);
    $myresult = $result[0];
```

I am looking to get decimal values upto 5 numbers, but once a negative value comes it results out as 0.000-1 instead of -0.00001

```
$myresultb = str_pad($mario, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$myresultf =  '0.'.$myresultb.'<br/>';
$total_score = 300;
echo  $myresultf;
```

Secondly I am new to php learning so am I doing this PHP correct or it needs improvement

I have a div to show total score like this

```
<div id="total_score"></div>
```

and another div to show current score which value comes as `echo $myresultf;`

```
 <div id="current_score"></div>
```

I want to update total score in real time with jquery wheneven button is clicked and  `<?php echo  $myresultf ?>` is refreshed in real time also

```
$("#play").click(function() {
var currentscore = $("#current_score").val();
var totalscore = $("#total_score").val();
how to do this.....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$max        =   100;
 $oray       =   1;
 $max_mal = (3 - $oray);


$total = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max_mal; $i++){
      $goli = mt_rand(3, 8);
      $total += $goli;
        $golis[] = $goli;
    } 

    foreach($golis as &$goli) {
        $goli = floor(($goli / $total) * $max);
          if ($goli == 0) {
            $goli = 1;
          }
     }
    $result =   array_pad($golis, 3, -1);
    shuffle($result);
    $myresult = $result[0];    
    $negative_var=false;

    if($myresult < 0)
    {
      $negative_var=true;

      $myresult = 0-$myresult;
    }

    $myresultb = str_pad($myresult, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $myresultf =  '0.'.$myresultb.'<br/>';

    if($negative_var)
      $myresultf="-".$myresultf;

    $total_score = 300;
    echo  $myresultf;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping this  can you plz tell me how to get this `$myresultf` value inside `<div id="current_score"></div>` with jquery instead of using php in fashion `<div id="current_score"><?php echo $myresultf ?></div>` as i want to update this value each time button is licked without refreshing page by taking it from this `array $myresult = $result[0];`

Comment: Use ajax for this

Answer (score 1):

simple use as follow:

```html
$myresultb =str_replace('-','',$myresultb);
if($myresult == -1) {
    $myresultf =  '-0.'.$myresultb.'<br/>';
}
else {
    $myresultf = '0.' . $myresultb . '<br/>';
}
```